# Rewrite domains to static html pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have 3 landings for 3 domains,

So I want:

`.com` to open `index.html`,
`.se` to open `index_sw.html`,
`.es` to open `index_es.html`

This is how I'm trying:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html [NC,QSA] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.se [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index_sw.html [NC,QSA] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.es [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index_es.html [NC,QSA]
```

but they are all resolving `index.html`,

Any idea what am I missing?

-EDIT-

Tried:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html [NC,QSA] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.se [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index_sw.html [NC,QSA] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.es [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index_es.html [NC,QSA]
```

But still seeing `index.html`

-EDIT-

```
Also tried with:

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.se$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /index_sw.html [L] 


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.es$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /index_es.html [L]
```

same result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.se$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /index_sw.html [L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.es$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /index_es.html [L]
```

Comment: Is `/www` your `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: I can see the full path in the FTP:
`/home/user/website/www/.htacess`

Comment: Are you still getting problem after my suggested code> Are `.htaccess`, `index.html` etc all in `/home/user/website/www/` folder? And are you sure .htaccess and mod_rewrite are enabled?

Comment: problem is that I'm not sure what you mean by DOCUMENT_ROOT, yes, they're all in same folder, thanks!

Comment: DocumentRoot is defined in your Apache config files for setting up your site.

Comment: Well, all the files are in the folder that I mentioned, and all the domains are pointed there..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43339/discussion-between-anubhava-and-toni-michel-caubet)